# Como parar execução de código Python por tempo?

Tags: python, python-requests

Como posso fazer para que um trecho de código seja executado por x segundos e depois pare?
No caso em especifico, estou esperando uma resposta de uma pagina usando request, mas se demorar mais de 5 segundos, quero parar e fazer a próxima requisição.

Answer (score 4):

Por padrão, [request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) aguardará indefinidamente pela resposta a uma solicitação.
Se quiser especificar um tempo limite para solicitação, use o parâmetro [`timeout`](https://docs.python-requests.org/pt_BR/latest/user/quickstart.html#timeouts)

O exemplo abaixo o tempo limite da solicitação será atingido após 10 segundos:

```
requests.get(`https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques`, timeout=10)
```

Também pode ser passado uma tupla como valor de timeout:

```
requests.get(`https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques`, timeout=(10, 5))
```

O primeiro elemento da tupla define o tempo limite que deve ser aguardado para se fazer uma conexão e segundo elemento é o tempo limite que deve ser aguardado para se fazer a leitura dos dados após conectado.

Comment: Muito bem, entendeu bem a duvida do OP +1